# In NUnit, how can I indicate that a 'DataPoint' is applicable to just one Theory?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-2.5

In `NUnit`, is there any way to indicate that a `Datapoint(s)Attribute` should be applied only to one theory only, if there is more than one theory in the same `TestFixture` class?

Reason I ask is that I have usually followed a unit test convention where all methods of a test class (CUT) are tested by multiple `[Test]` methods rolled into a 
single test fixture class, and am now trying to move away from parameterized tests toward `[Theory]`.

Or should I just continue to use the [Values / Range / Random](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) attributes of Parameterized tests for such tests?

e.g. Below, I want to ensure that different datapoints to the theories for add and divide:

```
// C.U.T.
public class BadMaths
{
    public int BadAdd(int x, int y) { return x + y - 1; }
    public int Divide(int x, int y) { return x / y; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class BadMathsTest
{
    // Ideally I want 2 x different datapoints - one for Add, and a different one for divide
    [Datapoints]
    private Tuple<int, int>[] _points = new Tuple<int, int>[]
        {
           new Tuple<int, int>(20, 10),
           new Tuple<int, int>(-10, 0),
        };

    [Theory]
    public void AddTheory(Tuple<int, int> point)
    {
        Assume.That((long)point.Item1 + (long)point.Item2 < (long)int.MaxValue);
        Assert.That(point.Item1 + point.Item2, Is.EqualTo(new BadMaths().BadAdd(point.Item1, point.Item2)));
    }

    [Theory]
    public void DivideTheory(Tuple<int, int> point)
    {
        Assume.That(point.Item2 != 0); // Seems the best I can do - test is inconclusive
        Assert.That(point.Item1 / point.Item2, Is.EqualTo(new BadMaths().Divide(point.Item1, point.Item2)));
    }

}
```

**Edit**

The example given above isn't a good example of `Theory` usage - it is a better fit to [`TestCaseSource`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5), and with the new Roslyn [`nameof`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#nameof-expressions) operator neither the `[DataPoints]` nor `[UsedImplicitly]` attributes are required on the source data.

```
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(_points)]
    public void EnsureAddPoints(Tuple<int, int> point)
    { ....
```

Comment: Similar to [XUnit's PropertyData](http://www.tomdupont.net/2012/04/xunit-theory-data-driven-unit-test.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there's any direct way of asking NUnit to use different datapoints of the same type for different theories.  However there are two possible ways you can work around:

The first is to use different TextFixture classes for the tests that require different datapoint values:

```
[TestFixture]
public class BadMathsAdditionTest
{
    // Ideally I want 2 x different datapoints - one for Add, and a different one for divide
    [Datapoints]
    private Tuple<int, int>[] _points = new Tuple<int, int>[]
    {
       new Tuple<int, int>(20, 10),
       new Tuple<int, int>(-10, 0),
    };

    // add tests that use these datapoints
    [Theory]
    public void AddTheory(Tuple<int, int> point)
    {
        Assume.That((long)point.Item1 + (long)point.Item2 < (long)int.MaxValue);
        Assert.That(point.Item1 + point.Item2, Is.EqualTo(new BadMaths().BadAdd(point.Item1, point.Item2)));
    }

}

[TestFixture]
public class BadMathsDivisionTest
{

    // Ideally I want 2 x different datapoints - one for Add, and a different one for divide
    [Datapoints]
    private Tuple<int, int>[] _points = new Tuple<int, int>[]
    {
       new Tuple<int, int>(20, 10),
    };

    // add test that use these datapoints

}
```

The second method requires a bit more work but arguably gives more readable code is to wrap each datapoint set in a different struct, like this:

```
// C.U.T.
public class BadMaths
{
    public int BadAdd(int x, int y) { return x + y - 1; }
    public int Divide(int x, int y) { return x / y; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class BadMathsTest
{

    public struct AdditionData
    {
        public int First { get; set; }
        public int Second { get; set; }
    }
    [Datapoints]
    private AdditionData[] _points = new AdditionData[]
    {
        new AdditionData{First=20, Second=10},
        new AdditionData{First=-10, Second=0}
    };


    public struct DivisionData
    {
        public int First { get; set; }
        public int Second { get; set; }
    }

    [Datapoints]
    private DivisionData[] _points2 = new DivisionData[]
    {
        new DivisionData{First=20, Second=10},
    };

    [Theory]
    public void AddTheory(AdditionData point)
    {
        Assume.That((long)point.First + (long)point.Second < (long)int.MaxValue);
        Assert.That(point.First + point.Second, Is.EqualTo(new BadMaths().BadAdd(point.First, point.Second)));
    }

    [Theory]
    public void DivideTheory(DivisionData point)
    {
        Assume.That(point.Second != 0); // Actually you probably want to keep this condition anyway. Second==0 would be a separate test
        Assert.That(point.First / point.Second, Is.EqualTo(new BadMaths().Divide(point.First, point.Second)));
    }

}
```

Comment: I've accepted, but would still like to see if there is a declarative way to restrict the target of a datasource :)

Comment: Thanks StuartLC. Having scoured the documentation, I'm fairly sure that there is currently no declarative way to restrict the datasource target, but I'll keep an eye out and post here if something turns up to prove me wrong.